# On a certain limit looking as a square root of a factorial function

Tags: limits, factorial

While computing the dimension of certain Specht modules I encountered following limit:

$$\lim\limits_{n \rightarrow \infty} (2^2. 3^3 \ldots  n^n)^{\frac{2}{n(n+1)}}$$

In case there would be written $n!$ instead of $2^2. 3^3 \ldots  n^n$ one could use Stirling formula in order to compute the limit, but this limit I do not see how to compute it. Intuitively I would except it to converge to $\infty$.

Do somebody has an idea? In any case thanks!

Comment: Tried taking logarithms?

Comment: After taking logarithms [Stolz–Cesàro theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stolz%E2%80%93Ces%C3%A0ro_theorem) could be of use.

Comment: Thanks for the tips! 
I tried indeed to take logarithms, but i got stuck. I just tried Stolz-Cesaro theorem. However the limit $\lim\limits_{n \rightarrow \infty} \frac{a_{n+1}-a_n}{b_{n+1}-b_n}$ do not exists, thus the theorem can not be used (if i am not mistaken).

Answer (score 0):

$$\ln((2^2\cdot 3^3\cdots n^n)^{\frac{2}{n(n+1)}})=2\frac{2\ln 2+3\ln 3+\cdots +n\ln n}{n(n+1)}\\\lim_{n\to\infty}2\frac{2\ln 2+3\ln 3+\cdots+n\ln n}{n(n+1)}=\lim_{n\to\infty}2\frac{(n+1)\ln(n+1)}{(n+2)(n+1)-(n+1)n}=\lim_{n\to\infty} 2\frac{\ln(n+1)}{2}=\infty$$

Comment: I only read now the full form of Stolz-Cesaro theorem. This indeed shows that the start limit also have to go to infinity. Thanks a lot for your help!

Comment: @GeoffreyJ No problem if you like my answer you can upvote it and/or accept it.